# Design of application that allows the communication between browser and hardware

Tags: java, web, browser, hardware

In this scenario. I have a web application, that runs in the browser, and now I want to access the scanner of the local desktop.

As far as i can see, the only option is installing some type of local agent in each computer, through java or an agent app (.exe).

Example: [scanner.js](https://asprise.com/scan/scannerjs/demo/scanner.js-demo.html)

My question is just about the logic, not code.

Ok, I have a website. Now how the website can connect and communicate with the agent? How can i define the communication port?

What is the concept design of this type of process between an agent that have access to hardware and the local browser?

Answer (score 0):

> Ok, I have a website. Now how the website can connect and communicate
>   with the agent? How can i define the communication port?

In common, agents provide Rest or SOAP API, and website script send JSON/XML requests. But don't foget about security and authentication.

List of lib and frameworks:

1. [Rest
   framework](https://github.com/Vedenin/useful-java-links#5-rest-frameworks),
2. [SOAP](https://github.com/Vedenin/useful-java-links#16-xml-and-soup),
3. [WebServers](https://github.com/Vedenin/useful-java-links#1-servers-web-server-and-application-server),
4. [Security and
   Authentication](https://github.com/Vedenin/useful-java-links#security-and-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is indeed a local agent that runs on the PC of the user. That local agent could be a web server with a port open to connect to from browser. Calls to the service should be protected so that others can't abuse the service. The communication could take place via websockets.

Resources that might be interesting to check are:

- [Tutorial CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)
- [NanoHTTPd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd)